# Why the increment of an integer on C# is executed after a function return its value?

Tags: c#, .net, function, compilation, increment

Why this two functions return different values?

When I call this function passing 0 as parameter it returns 1

```
public static int IncrementByOne(int number)
{
    return (number + 1);
}
```

However, when I call this function passing 0 as parameter it returns 0 even though the increment is executed and the number variable changes its value to 1 inside the method?

```
public static int IncrementByOne(int number)
{
    return number++;
}
```

What is the reason why the returned values of this two functions are different?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`number++` is a **postincrement**. It returns its current value before it is incremented. To get the same behaviour as in your first method, use a **preincrement** `++number`

See documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The value of the [post-increment (postfix) `++` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx) is the value of the operand before it is incremented. So if the current value is `2`, the operator saves `2`, increments it to `3` but returns the saved value.

For your function

```
public static int IncrementByOne(int number)
{
    return number++;
}
```

Look at the generated IL code to see what happens:

```
IncrementByOne:
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0        // load 'number' onto stack
    IL_0001:  dup            // copy number - this is the reason for the
                             // postfix ++ behavior
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1       // load '1' onto stack
    IL_0003:  add            // add the values on top of stack (number+1)
    IL_0004:  starg.s     00 // remove result from stack and put
                             // back into 'number'
    IL_0006:  ret            // return top of stack (which is
                             // original value of `number`)
```

The reason the postfix `++` operator returns the original (not the incremented) value is because of the `dup` statement - the value of `number` is on the stack twice and one of those copies stays on the stack by the `ret` statment at the end of the function so it gets returned. The result of the increment goes back into `number`.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your vote? If you think something is wrong with this answer, let me know.

Comment: The code and your description of it are opposites. You say that the value is returned before the increment, but *read the code*. The ret happens *after* the increment!

Comment: A correct statement would be "the value of the operation is the value of the operand before it is incremented".  So the sequence goes: evaluation, increment, return.  This is all clearly documented in the specification.

Comment: @EricLippert Ok, I may have mis-phrased it. I thought I wrote it out correctly. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Would it had been easier to say that at the point the method returns, the value on the stack is the value of `number` _before_ the increment (and therefore is the return value). The incremented value has been stored in the local but not pushed onto the stack.

Comment: @ScottPerham Perhaps it would've been easier but I didn't think of that. My original phrasing seemed clear to me - it was supposed to mean what you and Eric Lippert were suggesting but looking back, even I see that it was misleading at the least and perhaps downright wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Or, to point out the caveman approach...

```
public static int IncrementByOne(int number)
{
    number++;
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last function post-increments number; If you want immediate incremented value, you can try `return ++number;`